# skywalking agent NOT support java-grpc high versions

Tags: grpc-java, skywalking

I'm use latest skywalking agent(currently is 8.13.0), found trace span NOT reported for grpc 1.43.2 or 1.51.0 but reports for java-grpc 1.29.0 version.

**Environment**:

1. The app test source code is offical java-grpc example project: `HelloworldServer` and `HelloWorldClient`
2. invoke example's gRPC SayHello and watch the application tracing result in wkywalking web page.

With some research, found NettyClientStreamInstrumentation use fixed version for grpc netty 1.33.0

```
/**
 * Intercept constructor to obtain server IP.
 * grpc Low version(eg:1.6.0): use io.grpc.netty.NettyClientStream.
 * grpc High version(eg:1.33.1): use io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.grpc.netty.NettyClientStream.
 */
public class NettyClientStreamInstrumentation extends ClassInstanceMethodsEnhancePluginDefine {
...
```

But I'm not sure if it make effect for trace report.

There are some questions hope consult:

1. Is the code limit grpc report?
2. which java-grpc version support has tested?
3. how can I make sure the agent report or not report trace span?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am not following. Are you upgrading the gRPC dependency in agent codebase?

Comment: hi,  I think it should be the latest agent gRPC deps. Agent codebase is extract from  skywalking website tar file. I'm use latest skywalking agent jar which is 8.13.0, the grpc plugin is `apm-grpc-1.x-plugin-8.13.0.jar`.

Comment: These are two things. There is no relevant between agent's gRPC dependency and gRPC plugin.

1. gRPC dependency is for internal telemetry data reporting.
2. gRPC plugin is for tracing gRPC requests.

Comment: get it, seems other libs should be check. But how to check `gRPC dependency is for internal telemetry data reporting`? I'm use `grpc-all` and `skywalking-agent` tar. Not others yet.

Comment: If you mean internal dependency, then yes, gRPC has version requirements on netty as always. Choose the versions recommended on gRPC-java repository. SkyWalking agent sometimes bump the netty version due to CVE fix. If you plan to upgrade gRPC-java, then make sure the netty version matched.

Comment: Thanks. I will check skywalking netty version and which gRPC-java it will be support, but it's better to test as a result. It's also my confused of second question, there  not find a official web page list all agent version with supporting grpc-java version.

Comment: There is [supported list doc](https://skywalking.apache.org/docs/skywalking-java/next/en/setup/service-agent/java-agent/supported-list/). And it is more accurate to see the [plugin test coverage](https://github.com/apache/skywalking-java/blob/main/test/plugin/scenarios/grpc-scenario/support-version.list).

Comment: How you wrote the codes matters too, the tests can't cover it. That is how open-source works, various people contributed various plugins for different use cases.

Comment: Thanks for your patient. I'm willing contribute to it and make it better after success release our main production.

Answer (score 0):

grpc-java itself supports OpenCensus based tracing, that is for grpc internal events, e.g. a grpc message is sent or received, and retry attempts. (https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/blob/master/census/src/main/java/io/grpc/census/CensusTracingModule.java) It is unclear that the grpc tracing is enable or not in the agent.

The agent may have its own tracing instrumentation for its own requests.

So it is unclear you had question bout grpc-census tracing or the application's tracing. But it is unlikely that `NettyClientStreamInstrumentation`  affects the tracing generation itself.

When the span report is not generated, it also could be that the span/trace exporter config is not correct.

Comment: Does grpc-java version affect span/trace exporter config? The confuing things is low version of grpc-java(1.29.0) works but 1.43.2 not works with same environment.

Comment: I will clarify it in question, focus on applications's tracing with example's `SayHello `grpc API